# Strange apparent order of execution when debugging a program with Valgrind/GDB

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, valgrind, order-of-execution

It's been a while since I've used Valgrind more than for quick tests,
and I came across something I didn't quite understand when trying to 
debug a program written in C. I'm not sure if it's  something wrong with
my code or just something "low-level" that I don't know about.

The following piece of code is being executed (data is a struct):

```
... 
data = initialise();
setup(data);
printf("Hi2");
evolve(data);
...
```

where setup ends in

```
    ...
    printf("Setup done.\n");
    printf("Hi1");
}
```

but what Valgrind prints with

```
valgrind --vgdb=yes --track-origins=yes ./a.out config
```

is (before this, there are no errors; all the preset values of data are
printed correctly without problems.)

```
...
Setup done.
==3886== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==3886==    at 0x402BF2: evolve (generic_evolution.c:25)
==3886==    by 0x400AD3: main (main.c:19)
==3886==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==3886==    at 0x400B54: initialise (main.c:28)
==3886== 
==3886== Invalid write of size 4
==3886==    at 0x7FF0001C0: ???
==3886==    by 0x400AD3: main (main.c:19)
==3886==  Address 0xae00000007ff0004 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==3886== 
==3886== 
==3886== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3886==  General Protection Fault
==3886==    at 0x7FF0001C0: ???
==3886==    by 0x400AD3: main (main.c:19)
Hi1Hi2
...
```

After this, first few printfs from evolve are printed and the program
exits prematurely. If I run it without Valgrind, it crashes with a
segfault immediately after "Setup done.", without priting Hi1. Even more,
if I run the program with gdb and do

```
bt full
```

I can see not only the contents of data, but also variables declared in
the beginning of evolve, even though it seems that setup hasn't "really"
finished yet. According to gdb the segfault is caused by something that 
I'm not able to see (compiling with -g; and other variables showing up
just fine):

```
Finished setup.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffffffe200 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x00007fffffffe200 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
...
(prints data and variables declared in evolve)
```

Does anyone happen to know/be able to guess why it seems that the error occurs in evolve, before the last printf in setup is printed to stdout (and when executing normally, the segfault happens in such a strange spot, between two simple printfs)?

Comment: `printf("Setup done.\n");` vs `printf("Hi1");` - one of these flushes `stdout`, the other doesn't. And a backtrace like that shown is *usually* indicative of a stack-smash. Check your boundary constraints.

Comment: ...I guess that's why one shouldn't learn programming just for a specific purpose, I don't think I've ever seen/been told that. Thanks. My initial guess was indeed that the problem is probably in the memory allocation, I can't spot it yet but at least the weird debugging info is no longer making me question myself. But thanks again.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `evolve()` and step through to see what's breaking.  And if you want to do debug printing, consider using `fprintf()` to `stderr` which will flush the output after each call.